# Using makefiles while createing os

Tags: makefile, operating-system

( I am new to both programming and this webpage )

Well as I understand Linux have Makefiles ( I am going to start creating Os ) but I cant find how to make a makefile in windows any suggestions ( I dont want to download anything )

thnx for ur answers

Comment: Even if you could, what would be the purpose of that?  You'd just have a copy of the file.  Why not just copy the file normally?

Comment: Why copy the _contents_ and not just the file itself. This may fail depending on encoding types. If you do this, for whetever reason, validate the checksums afterwards.

Comment: Of course not. Executables are binary, not text, so you can't use a text editor to copy their binary code. Trust me - anyone who asks this question isn't going to be able to *change them too*. And how is this in any sense a programming question?

Comment: edited question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can simply copy the code from notepad++, as there are some characters that are not printable that you can copy (\n, BELL, NULL and so on).
However, if you write a python script to read the file in binary mode ("rb") then you can do it successfully (I'm speaking from experience).

Edit:
this is the python script that copies a file if you are interested:

```
INPUT_FILE = "C:/input.exe" # change it to the path of your existing file
OUTPUT_FILE = "C:/output.exe" # change it to the path of where you want your new file
input = open(INPUT_FILE, "rb")
data = input.read()
input.close()
output = open(OUTPUT_FILE, "wb")
output.write(data)
output.close()
```

Comment: ok thnx that helped me a lot but notepad++ doesnt show the python files' byte code